# How to mock varible that imported in tested module, and it is not a function parameter (do this with describe.each and on each test change mock value)

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I need to test function in my ts-module.

`module-to-test.ts`

```
import { config } from './app-config';

export const isSomethingWhatINeedSelector = createSelector(
    firstDependencySelector,
    secondDependencySelector,
    (first, second) => config.key && (first || !second)
);
```

But I don't want to write many test for this case, and I want to try to use 
`describe.each([[],[],[]])` functionality to reduce number of code lines.

And I need to change config.key on each iteration of describe.each.
When I do at the beginning of the test-file something like this:

```
jest.mock('./app-config', () => ({
    config: {
        key : false,
    },
}));
```

it works for the whole file and all the tests. I want to make mock inside "test/it" functions to change value of key dynamically.

Now I have that code, that `doesn't work` as expected

```
describe.each([
    [
        'should be ....',
        true, false
    ],
    [
        'should be ....',
        false, true
    ],
    /* and etc. ... [], [], [] ... only for questnion here is two params*/
])('Functionality of ...', (
    testTitle = '',
    mockStatusOfConfigKey,
    expected,
) => {
    const state = ... /* initial */

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
        /*....configuring the state*/
    }); 

    it(testTitle, () => {
        jest.mock('./app-config', () => ({ /*...or doMock(), that don't works*/
           config: {
              key : mockStatusOfConfigKey,
           },
        }));
        expect(isSomethingWhatINeedSelector(state)).toBe(expected);
    });
    });
```

Any ideas how to make mocks dynamically changable inside test functions?
`config.key is just true/false`

Comment: I would just pass config.key as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two important concepts from [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values) (which are also applicable to [TypeScript Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)):

> In ES6, imports are live read-only views on exported values

and

> while you can’t change the values of imports, you can change the objects that they are referring to.

---

`app-config` exports `config` *which is an object*.

`config` can't be assigned to something else, *but the object it refers to can be changed*.

Any code that imports `config` gets a live view of the object and will automatically see any modifications to the object:

```js
import { config } from './app-config';

...

  it(testTitle, () => {
    config.key = mockStatusOfConfigKey;  // modify the config object
    expect(isSomethingWhatINeedSelector(state)).toBe(expected); // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

Comment: But how this mock can be injected into OPs function?

Comment: @DimaVishnyakov `isSomethingWhatINeedSelector` uses the `config` object exported by `app-config`.  The test imports the `config` object as well.  Because both are *live bindings to the same object*, when the test changes the `key` property that change is seen in `isSomethingWhatINeedSelector`.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors Thank you! It is really works for me. But I can't even imagine that it will be so easy

Comment: @VladimirMedinsky Awesome, glad to hear it was helpful!